# how to fix "WARNING: terminal is not fully functional" error in command console?

Tags: git, command-line

I was using hg, now I am converting to Git.

But after installing it, every time I do "git diff" or "git log", I get this error: WARNING: terminal is not fully functional.

How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Q: How are you connecting to Git?

For example, if you're using Cygwin on Windows, try this:

```
TERM=msys
```

If you're on Linux (or connecting to a Linux server via putty), then try this:

```
export TERM=msys
```

If you're running from a Windows command prompt:

```
<Rclick>Computer, Properties, 
  [Advanced System Settings], [Advanced], [Environment Variables]
  Create a new System variable "TERM", value "msys"
```

Comment: thank you! was using windows!

Comment: To set it once in Windows, use `set TERM=msys`. To set it permanently, use `setx TERM msys /M`.

Comment: I had *"dumb"* in there. It was introduced by the installation of *"Strawberry Perl"* modifying system environment variables. Edited my `/~.bashrc` file adding `export TERM=cygwin` to get ti working. So a little different to what has been answered here (and with the duplicate).

Comment: Hi Paulsm4. Thanks, your answer helped me. Can you please tell me `why` this error occurs ? What is this `term` and what does it do ?

Comment: @paulsm4, What exactly does "not fully functional" mean anyway? I ignored the error, didn't fix it, yet things seem to be pretty fine.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone gets this using Git Extensions, check the setting for `Path to linux tools...`. Mine was set to `C:\cygwin`. Changing it to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\` fixed it for me.