# Using git log on MAC OS terminal 'WARNING:terminal is not fully functional'

Tags: macos, git, terminal, export

I see responses to this such as [Why does git diff on Windows warn that the "terminal is not fully functional"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949956/why-does-git-diff-on-windows-warn-that-the-terminal-is-not-fully-functional?lq=1)
and 
[how to fix "WARNING: terminal is not fully functional" error in command console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219266/how-to-fix-warning-terminal-is-not-fully-functional-error-in-command-console)

However, these are for windows and I am just wondering if this applies equally to MAC.

Furthermore, the best voted responses are:
"
accepted
Q: How are you connecting to Git?
For example, if you're using Cygwin on Windows, try this:
TERM=msys
If you're on Linux (or connecting to a Linux server via putty), then try this:
export TERM=msys
"

AND

"
accepted
Can be fixed by adding the following line to ~/.bashrc:

export TERM=msys
"
---> What exactly is 'export TERM=msys' ACTUALLY DOING to the terminal??
I don't understand the suggested literature linked to below these answers.
Thank you kindly.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at other questions containing code snippets, then re-thinking your formatting a little :) `export TERM...` sets the [environmental variable](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html#ENVREF) `TERM` to a value which should be the [name of the currently running terminal](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Environment_Variables). In this case, `msys`, which is (I think) the microsoft windows terminal.

Comment: So I understand that this error is occurring because of the differences between shell mode and term mode, ie where shell mode falls short, a terminal emulator might not.  Although, I don't know how many benefits I will lose by going to term mode. I am now trying term mode, which is simply:     M-x term

Comment: I don't like term mode :/